# How to request url which has space and dot in ios?

Tags: ios, json, namespaces, nsdata, nsurl

I am trying to request the following URL and i am getting an error saying "Data parameter is nil". i had found that the 'seller_name' has got space and 'amount' has got dot(.). I think this is the problem that is being caused by the URL. So is there any way to send URL having space and dot without loosing the information?

```
NSURL *url1 = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"192.168.1.85/localex_postsale.html?contactid=%@&exchangeid=%@&token=%@&buyerid=%@&seller_name=%@&desc=%@&amount=%@&sellerid=%@",contactid,exchangeid,token,buyervalue,sellers,_Description,_Amount,contactid]];
NSError *errors1;
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];
NSDictionary *json1 = (NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:kNilOptions error:&errors1];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method in `NSString`, *e.g.*:

```
NSString *myUnencodedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"192.168.1.85/localex_postsale.html?contactid=%@&exchangeid=%@&token=%@&buyerid=%@&seller_name=%@&desc=%@&amount=%@&sellerid=%@",contactid,exchangeid,token,buyervalue,sellers,_Description,_Amount,contactid]
NSString *encodedString = [myUnencodedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:encodedString]
...
```

Cf.: Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a).

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because **URL should not contain white space**. It should be encode to `%20` if there is any space. We can encode space and special character in `NSString` using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` as below

```
NSString *string = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"192.168.1.85/localex_postsale.html?contactid=%@&exchangeid=%@&token=%@&buyerid=%@&seller_name=%@&desc=%@&amount=%@&sellerid=%@",contactid,exchangeid,token,buyervalue,sellers,_Description,_Amount,contactid]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url1 = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:string];
NSError *errors1;
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];
NSDictionary *json1 = (NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:kNilOptions error:&errors1];
```